# xcode, Intel iMac, Could not find module 'SwiftyTesseract' for target 'arm64-apple-ios-simulator'; found: x86_64-apple-ios-simulator

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode, x86-64, arm64

A coworked and I have both the same model and configuration of our workstations:

- 21.5" Intel-based iMacs
- MacOS Ventura 13.5
- XCode 14.3.1 (14E300c)

We have a flutter project, started with flutter 2.x, and later upgraded to flutter 3.x.
The project compiles with no issues on my coworker's system, but on mine it fails with this error:

```
Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): Could not find module 'SwiftyTesseract' for target 'arm64-apple-ios-simulator'; found: x86_64-apple-ios-simulator, at:
/Users/user/Projects/project-name/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/SwiftyTesseract/SwiftyTesseract.framework/Modules/SwiftyTesseract.swiftmodule
/Users/user/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_mrz_scanner-2.1.0/ios/Classes/MRZScannerView.swift:2:7
```

The error happens both in debug and release modes.
I have tried fiddling with build settings: `Architectures`, `Build active architecture only`, `Excluded architectures`, `Supported platforms`, `VALID_ARCHS`... but I wasn't able to ever build the project on my machine. Does not run on simulator, does not run on real device, does not even build for generic "Any iOS device" (or simulator), nothing.

Does anyone have any idea what XCode is expecting?

Additional info, `flutter doctor`:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.10.6, on macOS 13.5 22G74 darwin-x64, locale en-GB)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.0)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.3.1)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.3)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.81.0)
[✓] Connected device (3 available)
[✓] Network resources

• No issues found!
```